Prerequisite conditions for the Law of Total Expectation
Say, for example, random variable $X\:|\:M=m$ is Poisson distributed with rate parameter $m$ and random variable $M$ is exponentially distributed with rate parameter $1$.
To find the moment-generating function of $X$, according to my instructor, we can use the law of total expectation:
$$\psi_X(t)=E[e^{tX}]=E[ E[e^{tX}|M]]=\cdots$$
According to Allan Gut's An Intermediate Course in Probability, $E\left[|e^{tX}|\right]$ needs to be finite for us to apply the law of total expectation, so why is $E\left[|e^{tX}|\right]$ finite in the example? Can we show that it is finite without finding the distribution of $X$?

Actually, the law of iterated expectation $\mathrm E[X]=\mathrm E\bigl[\mathrm E[X\mid Y]\bigr]$ holds even if $\mathrm E[X]=+\infty$ or if $\mathrm E[X]=-\infty$. We simply need the expectation $\mathrm E[X]$ to exist.
Decompose $X=X_+-X_-$ into its positive and negative parts. The expectation $\mathrm E[X]$ is not defined iff $\mathrm E[X_+]=\mathrm E[X_-]=+\infty$. Hence, the requirement of the law to hold is
$$\min\bigl\{\mathrm E[X_+],\mathrm E[X_-]\bigr\}<+\infty,$$
i.e. they cannot be both infinite.
